# Como usar ID de Sesión en PHP para traer datos de MySQL?

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo una bd con dos tablas una llamada "usuarios" y la otra "datos", tengo un loguin que usa perfecto los datos de "usuarios" para acceder a x pagina pero me gustaría que cuando x usuario ingrese se haga una consulta a la bd y me traiga los datos relevantes de su id de la tabla "datos" estoy tratado de usar el id de sesión (identificación de usuario en el loguin) pero no funciona: tengo este código pero no logro que funcione espero me puedan ayudar:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }   
?>
<html>
<head>
<table border="0" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'casano', 'temp*2021*', 'sbdb2021');
    $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM `laboral` WHERE `Identificacion`= '".$_SESSION['usuario']."'");
    while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
      
 <tr>
    <td>
        <h4 align="center">CERTIFICACIÓN</h4>
        <br>  

        <p align="justify">Certifica que el señor (a) <? echo "".$row['Nombre']; ?> Identificado con Cedula de Ciudadanía No.  <? echo number_format ("".$row['Identificacion']); ?> se encuentra vinculado laboralmente            
        <br>
        <br>
        La presente certificación se expide a solicitud del interesado el día <? echo $hoy=date("d/m/y"); ?> dirigida a 
    
</tr>
<?  } ?>    

</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Cosas a corregir:***

1. Cambia esto:

   ```
   while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
   ```

   por esto:

   ```
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
   ```

   porque cuando llamas a las columnas usas `$row` en lugar de `$resultado`.
2. Cambia:

   ```
   <? echo "".$row['Nombre']; ?>
   ```

   por esto

   ```
   <? echo $row['Nombre']; ?>
   ```

   porque no tiene ningún sentido hacer un `echo` de una cadena vacia (`""`) y luego concatenarla (`.`) con la columna `Nombre`.
3. Cambia:

   ```
   <? echo number_format ("".$row['Identificacion']); ?>
   ```

   por esto:

   ```
   <? echo number_format($row['Identificacion']); ?>
   ```

   por lo mismo de antes, es el mismo caso, pero aquí debes juntar la función `number_format` con el paréntesis también.
4. Por último, cambia esto:

   ```
   <? echo $hoy=date("d/m/y"); ?>
   ```

   por esto:

   ```
   <? echo date("d/m/y"); ?>
   ```

   porque esa asignación a la variable `$hoy` no tiene sentido tampoco, pues no la usas en el resto de código, y además no te mostraria la fecha de ese modo.

Ya nos diras si ahora te funciona todo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, No en el ambiente de pruebas aparece Parse error: syntax error linea 73 algo en el PHP no esta funcionando

Comment: @MauricioVergara Vaya, lo siento, ¿pero que pone en la linea 73?  ¿Algo de lo que he pedido modificar yo?

Comment: @MauricioVergara: Acabo de repasar los cambios que te he propuesto y ninguno deberia darte error de sintaxis, son todos correctos.  Debes cambiar **exactamente** lo que he propuesto y no ir más allá, por ejemplo en esta **línea**: `while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>` yo te he propuesto cambiar solo `while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($query))` y no el resto de ella que debes dejar como está: `{ ?>`... ¿quizás es eso?